# Need to send an alert if a job has not started by particular time, no alert raised if the job is paused

Tags: autosys

So we have this interesting problem. Say we have an autosys job that looks like this

```
insert_job: test_alert_job job_type: CMD
command: true
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_times: "16:18"
must_start_times: "16:19"
owner: test_account
machine: test
```

Success of this job is a pre-requisite for a number of other jobs. Our use case is, if the above job does not start by 14:15 an alert needs to be sent out, if this job is paused, no alert should be sent out and the jobs that depend on this job should **not** run.

I have tested a number of options, I have put the above job **ON_HOLD**, the job does not execute but we an alert is raised when trying:

```
jr test_alert_job -d

Job Name                                                         Last Start           Last End             ST Run/Ntry Pri/Xit
________________________________________________________________ ____________________ ____________________ __ ________ _______

test_alert_job                                                   -----                -----                OH 0/0             

  Status/[Event]  Time                 Ntry ES  ProcessTime           Machine
  --------------  --------------------- --  --  --------------------- ----------------------------------------
  [STARTJOB]      09/10/2019 16:18:00    0  PD  09/10/2019 16:18:00   
    <Event was scheduled based on job definition.>
  [CHK_START]     09/10/2019 16:19:00    0  PD  09/10/2019 16:19:00   
    <Event was scheduled based on job definition.>
  [*** ALARM ***]
    MUST_START_ALARM  09/10/2019 16:19:00    0  PD  09/10/2019 16:19:05   
    <CHK_START criteria has not been satisfied for JOB: test_alert_job>
```

So this is not behaving as we would like. I have then tried **ON_ICE** option, the job did not run, alert did not trigger but the jobs that are dependent on the job that is **ON_ICE** are triggered, this is not the correct result.

Does autosys support functionality of pausing a job, not throwing an alert and also not kicking off jobs that the paused job is a pre-requisite of?